Update Trigger that inserts into a log table for all the values that were updated
I have a trigger that only logs when the manager is updated. I need to change it so that it inserts a record for every field that was updated.
For example this statement will insert 3 records in the table test_UpdateLog:
Update Test set Manager='A',Location='B',Department='D';
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_test_UpdateLog]
ON [dbo].[test]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.test_UpdateLog(TableName,PrimaryKeyValue,ColumnName,OldValue,NewValue,UpdatedBy)
      SELECT 'test',i.Email,'Manager', d.Manager, i.Manager,USER_NAME()
      FROM Inserted i
      INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.Email = d.Email
      WHERE d.Manager <> i.Manager

END;


I don't see any reason to join Inserted on Deleted - I've actually never seen that before. Why are you doing that? Are you trying to filter the records you log to only include some changes and not others? Interesting ... I suppose its more common to just log all the changes and then you can easily get changes of manager (or anything other change) from your audit table.

@topsail I would say its very common to join inserted to deleted to detect changes :)

@Martin as a simple approach, just duplicate your code 3 times, once per column you wish to detect changes. What exactly are you stuck on? You are expected to have a go and be asking us about an issue you got stuck on as opposed to asking us to write it all.

A lot of people like to do this log changes per column thing but come back a while later because they cannot figure out how to display and use this data in a proper format because they want to correlate them together. Just log new values or old values or if you are really worried both old and new, values and be done with it, your future self will thank you (and me)

Another thing is the datatype issue, let's say your log table looks like: LogID, TableID, Date, FieldName, Old, New, then all columns should match the Old/New datatypes, which usually is not the case

Honestly, it feels like a better solution here would be a temporal table.

@DaleK, I just listed 3 fields as an example, but this table has more than 20 fields. Now you see why I don't want to duplicate the code 20 times. I'm looking for a solution to fit all.

You need to say that in your question otherwise how will we know?

You might find something useful in this vintage answer.

You can use the for json unpivot-trick to collect diffs without specifying 20 columns. But yeah, don't seem like you want to give too much info, so voting on unclear

One method is just to store all the changes all the time ... this is very typical in my experience.
You can then query for a particular change that you are interested in - see the last query in this example, where I query for only the changes in manager.
CREATE TABLE dbo.Manager (
    Id INT,
    Email VARCHAR(50),
    Manager VARCHAR(50),
    [Location] VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id))

CREATE TABLE dbo.Audit_Manager (
    AuditAction CHAR(1),
    AuditActionDateTime DATETIME,
    AuditActionBy VARCHAR(50),
    Id INT,
    Email VARCHAR(50),
    Manager VARCHAR(50),
    [Location] VARCHAR(50))
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER Manager_AfterUpdate ON dbo.Manager
FOR UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Manager (
        AuditAction,
        AuditActionDateTime,
        AuditActionBy, Id,
        Email,
        Manager,
        [Location])
    SELECT 
        'I',
        GETDATE(),
        USER_NAME(),
        Deleted.Id,
        Deleted.Email,
        Deleted.Manager,
        Deleted.[Location]
    FROM 
        Deleted
END
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER Manager_AfterDelete ON dbo.Manager
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit_Manager (
        AuditAction,
        AuditActionDateTime,
        AuditActionBy,
        Id,
        Email,
        Manager,
        [Location])
    SELECT 
        'D',
        GETDATE(),
        USER_NAME(),
        Deleted.Id,
        Deleted.Email,
        Deleted.Manager,
        Deleted.[Location]
    FROM 
        Deleted
END
GO

-- Test Runner
INSERT INTO dbo.Manager (Id, Email, Manager, [Location])
VALUES 
    (1, 'abc@example.com', 'John', 'X'),
    (2, 'def@example.com', 'Paul', 'X')
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
UPDATE dbo.Manager SET Email = 'ghi@example.com' WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
UPDATE dbo.Manager SET Email = 'jkl@example.com' WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
UPDATE dbo.Manager SET Manager = 'Mary' WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
UPDATE dbo.Manager SET [Location] = 'Y' WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
UPDATE dbo.Manager SET Manager = 'Jane' WHERE Id = 1

-- ---------------------------------------------------
-- View changes (each row is compared to the next row)
-- ---------------------------------------------------
;WITH delta AS (
SELECT 
    AuditAction,
    AuditActionDateTime, 
    AuditActionBy,
    Id,
    Email,
    Manager,
    [Location]
FROM dbo.Audit_Manager m
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    NULL AS AuditAction,
    NULL AS AuditActionDateTime, 
    NULL AS AuditActionBy,
    Id,
    Email,
    Manager,
    [Location]
FROM dbo.Manager m
)
SELECT * 
FROM delta 
ORDER BY 
    Id, 
    IIF(AuditActionDateTime IS NULL, 0, 1),
    AuditActionDateTime DESC

-- --------------------------------------------
-- View a particular change (change of manager)
-- --------------------------------------------
;WITH delta AS (
    SELECT 
        AuditAction,
        AuditActionDateTime, 
        AuditActionBy,
        Id,
        Email,
        Manager,
        [Location]
    FROM dbo.Audit_Manager m
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        NULL AS AuditAction,
        NULL AS AuditActionDateTime, 
        NULL AS AuditActionBy,
        Id,
        Email,
        Manager,
        [Location]
    FROM dbo.Manager m
),
delta_ordered AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY AuditActionDateTime DESC) AS RN
    FROM delta
)
SELECT 
    t1.AuditAction,
    t1.AuditActionDateTime,
    t1.AuditActionBy,
    t1.Id,
    t1.Manager AS Manager_Was,
    t2.Manager AS Manager_Is
FROM 
    delta_ordered t1
    INNER JOIN delta_ordered t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
    AND t1.RN = t2.RN-1
    AND t1.Manager <> t2.Manager
ORDER BY 
    t1.Id,
    t1.RN


I've used something like the following in the past:
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_test_UpdateLog]
ON [dbo].[test]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.test_UpdateLog (
        TableName, PrimaryKeyValue, ColumnName, OldValue, NewValue, UpdatedBy
    )
    SELECT 'test', i.Email, c.ColumnName, c.OldValue, c.NewValue, USER_NAME()
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.Email = d.Email
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  -- This just seeds the types and column names
            CAST(null AS SYSNAME) AS ColumnName,
            CAST(null AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS OldValue,
            CAST(null AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewValue
        WHERE 1 = 0
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Manager', d.Manager, i.Manager
                  WHERE d.Manager IS DISTINCT FROM i.Manager
        UNION ALL SELECT 'OtherColumn', d.OtherColumn, i.OtherColumn
                  WHERE d.OtherColumn IS DISTINCT FROM i.OtherColumn
        ...
    ) c
END;

Note that OldValue and NewValue may include nulls.
The recently added (but awkwardly named) IS DISTINCT FROM cleanly identifies changes - including those to/from null that required special handling prior to SQL Server 2022. If you are using an earlier version, you may need something like the following to properly detect changes on nullable columns:
                  WHERE d.Manager <> i.Manager
                  OR (d.Manager IS NULL AND i.Manager IS NOT NULL)
                  OR (d.Manager IS NOT NULL AND i.Manager IS NULL)

There might be a slight performance gain for large text columns (and perhaps others) if you first test the UPDATE(column_name) special trigger function before doing the compare:
                  WHERE UPDATE(Manager)
                  AND d.Manager IS DISTINCT FROM i.Manager
-- or
                  WHERE UPDATE(Manager)
                  AND (
                      d.Manager <> i.Manager
                      OR (d.Manager IS NULL AND i.Manager IS NOT NULL)
                      OR (d.Manager IS NOT NULL AND i.Manager IS NULL)
                  )

Additional notes:

If you also want to log inserts and deletes, change the INNER JOIN for a FULL OUTER JOIN and also replace the PK reference i.Email with COALESCE(i.Email, d.Email).
If you care about format and precision of values like date/times or float columns, you can include explicit conversions like CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), i.SomeDate, 121) or CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), i.SomeFloatValue, 3).
If you care about case sensitive changes ('ABC' vs 'Abc') or trailing space changes ('ABC' vs 'ABC '), you can force binary compares with CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), d.Manager) IS DISTINCT FROM CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), i.Manager).
If you decide to implement this across multiple tables, you can create a stored procedure that generates and applies dynamic SQL to handle the customized triggers for each table. (Be sure to use QUOTENAME(...), and QUOTENAME(..., '''') to safely inject the table names and column names.)
If you need combine change values, you can use combining expressions like STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c.ColumnName, ': ', c.OldValue), ', ') AS OldValueList together with an appropriate GROUP BY. (Note that CONCAT() quietly maps null values to empty strings. If you want custom handling, you can add an explicit ISNULL() mapping.)

